# Angular select all visible in list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say you have the following `ng-repeat`:

```
    <ul class="list-group">
    <ng-user-item
            ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search" user="user" ng-if="assigned.indexOf(user.id) < 0"
            ng-click="selectFunction(user);"></ng-user-item>
</ul>
```

Now as you can see this has a filter.

when the filter is not `null` i have the following button:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-if="search.division != null" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Select all</button>
```

when this button is pressed i want a list of all `ng-user-item` that is visible.

How can this be done with angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you change your `ng-repeat` to this it should work:

```
ng-repeat="user in filteredUsers = (users | filter:search)"
```

You can now use `filteredUsers` as a normal scope variable.